# Haskell/HSpec: Understanding error message

Tags: haskell

I have the following function that is supposed to return the last but one element of a list:

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast [] = error "List has less than one element!"
myButLast [x] = error "List has less than one element!"
myButLast [x,_] = x
myButLast (_:xs) = myButLast xs
```

It works for all special cases when I load it into `ghci`, but when I try to test it using `HSpec`, I get an error when running this spec:

```
main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do

  describe "myButLast" $ do

    -- removed other specs --

    it "throws an error when called with a singleton list" $
      myButLast [1] `shouldThrow` anyErrorCall
```

This is the error message:

```
No instance for (Num (IO a0)) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (IO a0))
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `myButLast', namely `[1]'
    In the first argument of `shouldThrow', namely `myButLast [1]'
```

Interestingly, the compiler does not complain when test `myButLast []` instead of `myButLast [1]`, although the results of both expressions are defined exactly the same.

Comment: Take a look at the type of `shouldThrow`: `shouldThrow :: Exception e => IO a -> Selector e -> Expectation`.

Comment: @simon but why does it work when I test `myButLast []` then?

Comment: `myButLast [1]` is of type `Int`. `myButLast []` is of type `IO a` if we infere the type of `[]` from the spec.

Comment: @simon why is `myButLast [1]` of a different type than `myButLast []`? I mean the are defined exactly the same.

Comment: Uh, yeah that wasn't quite correct: `myButLast [1]` is of type `Num a => a`. A numeric literal is infered to belong to the `Num` typeclass. But `[]` could be a list of anything, even `[IO a]`.

Comment: I guess you should simply take a more sane approach to error handling: Take a look at [this chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html) from RWH.

Comment: @simon How can `myButLast [1]` be of type `Num a => a`? The definition says `myButLast [x] = error "List has less than one element!"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57992/discussion-between-zero-divisor-and-simon).

Answer (score 1):

As simon pointed out:

**`myButLast [1]` simply has the wrong type**, namely `Num a => a`, while `shouldThrow` expects a first argument of type `IO a`.

So, the more interesting question is:

**Why doesn't the compiler complain about the type of `myButLast []`?**

The reason for this is: As the literal `[]` can also be of type `[IO a]`, the compiler infers the type of `myButLast []` to be `IO a`, because this is the only thing that would be a valid first argument to `shouldThrow`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question behind the question: to write the test, you want to use `evaluate`:

```
import Control.Exception.Base

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do

  describe "myButLast" $ do

    it "throws an error when called with a singleton list" $
      evaluate (myButLast [1]) `shouldThrow` anyErrorCall
```